# Handling multiple return parameters from RHS of function given to an ODE solver

Tags: python, scipy, ode

The ODE solvers in Python take the RHS of the function as an arguemnt. This function is supposed to signature `f(t, y *args)`. In general, `y` can be a numpy array and `f` will return an array `ydot` with same size as that of `y`. The syntax, however, demands that `f` should only return one thing and only one thing: the `ydot` array (or float is y is also a float). The ODE solver internally calls `f` as many times as it desires in order to reach convergence.

However in my case, this `f` is returning a tuple. Not just `ydot`, but a few more arrays. Now I can move this part outside `f` and call it after solver has reached convergence. But then I have changed the behavior, as the those parameters are not being updated at every time-step calculation (which should happen). So, I need to have that part of code there. But the syntax for the solvers like `scipy.integrate_solve_ivp` demands that `f` should return only `ydot`. So, I have no way to 'catch' the extra parameters and pass back to `f` when the solver calls it again.

Here below is a code which gives the general idea (note this snippet is just a stand-in for my actual code, which I cannot share, but the gist is same, my RHS of the function returns a tuple):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

# Define the RHS function
def f(t, y, param1, param2):
    # Calculate the derivative dy/dt
    ydot = np.sin(t) * y[0] + np.cos(t) * y[1]  # Example derivative equation

    # Calculate additional parameters
    param1 = some_func_1(ydot, param1)
    param2 = some_func_1(ydot, param2)

    # Return ydot and additional parameters as a tuple
    return ydot, param1, param2

# Define the time span and initial condition
t_span = (0, 5)
y0 = np.random.rand(2)  # Random initial condition

# Solve the ODE using solve_ivp
sol = solve_ivp(f, t_span, y0, args=(param1, param2))
```

`some_func_1` and `some_func_2` are some functions which take the param1 and param2 and do some modifications on it.

I tried looking into the `events` argument of `solve_ivp`, but it did not work. I guess it is for something else.

But this seems like a problem that someone must have encountered before, right? One workaround I can see is use of global variables, where I don't return the extra parameters instead store them in a global list or a global variable or something. But I think global variables are dangerous as they can introduce bugs. So I am looking for a more approach.

EDIT:

I just realised something: is it possible to be `args` of `solve_ivp` take functions itself? So the expression becomes:

```
sol = solve_ivp(f, t_span, y0, args=(some_func_1(param1), some_func_2(param2))
```

But even here, the problem of catching the return by `some_func_1` remains.

Comment: What are `param1` and `param2` used for? I don't see them anywhere else in your code.

Comment: @jared I am so sorry, the example code I gave did not clearly reflect my actual code. I have made the changes now. Please have a look.

Comment: @jared Now you can see that, basically the arguments to the function `f`, should get modified at every internal call of `f` by the solver.

Comment: `param1` and `param2` are computed, but you don't show how they're necessary for your function; they are never used after they're defined. If you just had `def f(t, y): return np.sin(t) * y[0] + np.cos(t) * y[1]`, it would seem that you would not have lost any functionality.

Comment: @jared Please have a look once more. I apologize, my initial code was missing the true picture.

Comment: As I keep trying to tell you, you're not doing anything with `param1` or `param2`. You just define them and return them. They have no actual effect on your differential equation (at least none that you show).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254468/discussion-between-peakcipher-and-jared).

Comment: You can write a wrapper tto `f` that only returns the `[0]` value.

Comment: If you have variables that change during integration, then these are additional components of the state. Only constant values should be parameters. There is no way to inject changed parameters into the solver if used in the straightforward way. You might get there if you construct a class around the ODE function. But always consider that the solver is a black box, it can call on arbitrary modifications of the state at arbitrary times in any unsorted order. // Perhaps it would be instructive if you implemented a time loop using RK2 or RK4 that realizes the scheme as you imagine.

Answer (score 0):

With care it is possible to pass `args` objects to the function, and modify them.  The objects need to be mutable, such as arrays or lists.

For example, taking the `expoential_decay` example, let's add a means of collecting all `t` values.  I'l define `par` as a list, and use `append` to modify it in-place.  I could have done something with an array, but this was the easiest thing to think of.

```
In [316]: def exponential_decay(t, y): return -0.5 * y
     ...: def f(t,y,par):
     ...:     val = exponential_decay(t,y)
     ...:     par.append(t)
     ...:     return val
     ...: par = []
     ...: sol = integrate.solve_ivp(f, [0, 10], [2, 4, 8], args=(par,))
In [317]: sol
Out[317]: 
  message: The solver successfully reached the end of the integration interval.
  success: True
   status: 0
        t: [ 0.000e+00  1.149e-01  1.264e+00  3.061e+00  4.816e+00
             6.574e+00  8.333e+00  1.000e+01]
        y: [[ 2.000e+00  1.888e+00 ...  3.107e-02  1.351e-02]
            [ 4.000e+00  3.777e+00 ...  6.214e-02  2.702e-02]
            [ 8.000e+00  7.553e+00 ...  1.243e-01  5.403e-02]]
      sol: None
 t_events: None
 y_events: None
     nfev: 44
     njev: 0
      nlu: 0
In [318]: len(par)
Out[318]: 44
In [319]: np.array(par)
Out[319]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.02      ,  0.02297531,  0.03446296,  0.09190123,
        0.10211248,  0.11487653,  0.11487653,  0.3446296 ,  0.45950614,
        1.03388881,  1.13600129,  1.26364188,  1.26364188,  1.62303707,
        1.80273466,  2.70122262,  2.86095382,  3.06061781,  3.06061781,
        3.41171646,  3.58726578,  4.4650124 ,  4.62105624,  4.81611105,
        4.81611105,  5.16778045,  5.34361515,  6.22278865,  6.37908617,
        6.57445806,  6.57445806,  6.92622442,  7.1021076 ,  7.98152352,
        8.13786412,  8.33328988,  8.33328988,  8.66663191,  8.83330292,
        9.66665798,  9.81480999, 10.        , 10.        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ODE appears to be unaffected by the values of `param1` and `param2`. So, I recommend removing them from the ODE and simply computing them afterward using the solution you get from `solve_ivp`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def f(t, y):
    return np.sin(t) * y[0] + np.cos(t) * y[1]

def compute_params(t, y):
    raise NotImplementedError

t_span = (0, 5)
y0 = np.random.default_rng(42).random(2)
sol = solve_ivp(f, t_span, y0)

param1, param2 = compute_params(sol.t, sol.y)
```